# A problem with the proof of a proposition

Tags: group-theory

I have a problem with the proof of Proposition 5.1. of the article of Ito.(Noboru Itˆo. On finite groups with given conjugate types. I.
Nagoya Math. J., 6:17–28, 1953.).
I don't know what is "e" and "e-1" in the proof.

I'd be really greatfull if someone help me.You can find the pdf file in this link.

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-6/issue-none/On-finite-groups-with-given-conjugate-types-I/nmj/1118799473.full)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would appear that $e$ is a group. Whenever the author writes $e-1$ they actually have "some group":$e-1$, so they just mean the index of $e$ in the group, minus one.

As to what $e$ is I am not sure, but I would guess it is related to $E$. I am not even sure whether $E$ is a group or an element, but most of the time it appears to be an element, and I would guess that $e$ is the group generated by $E$.

Edit: As Derek Holt has commented below, $e$ is probably the trivial group, and hence $[G:e]$ is just the order of $G$.

Comment: I believe that $e$ is just the trivial subgroup of $G$, and that $[C(P):e-1]$ is a typo: as is clear from the following equations, it should be $([C(P):e]-1)$. (I've written $C(P)$ for the centralizer of $P$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, I thought that it may be the trivial group, but I didn't know why something like $|C(P)|$ was not used instead - I guess it all means the same thing. Thank you

Comment: I think so($e=\{e\}$). In this case the inequality corresponds with the proof.